# Adding HTML forms to email

Tags: html, email

I have created an HTML form and can email the form to an email address. But when the recipient fills in the form and submits it, my server doesn't receive any of the filled in values.

Is it possible to embed an HTML form in an email and have clients process it correctly?

Answer (score 11):

We did some fairly extensive research about HTML forms in emails for a client of ours. The bottom line is that it barely works, so it’s best to link to a form in a browser.

Answer (score 6):

What Quentin said holds water, many email clients (cough, outlook) are very specific in regards to their support for HTML emails. In fact most don't even support div's or embedded `<style>` blocks. Let alone an HTML form.

Your best bet is to use a URL that they click on, which in-turn opens up a form for them to fill out. If you need to capture some of their information automatically (such as email). you can generate query strings and in your mailer have it add the information in dynamicallly..

i.e; `<a href="http://awesomeform.com/form.php?email=$client_email">`

In email it would look like: `http://awesomeform.com/form.php?email=myemail@email.com`

#### Either way

If you are insistent on attempting this, use the email boilerplate to get you started. It has a ton of "best practices" and tips/tricks built right into it.

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 5):

Complex HTML doesn't mix with many email clients. Forms are especially poorly supported.

Link to an HTML document available over HTTP instead. People can click a link and open it in a regular web browser.

Comment: Thanks :) unfortunately i already know this, i cant use a link or post an attached file, i have to created html form embedded in email, its for a client who does not have access to internet.

Comment: Oh. I missed the "click reply" bit. There is nothing you can do about that. I'd use "TYPE YOUR ANSWER HERE" placeholders.