# sending a formatted email

Tags: html, css, sendmail

I want to send email to my users on certain events,
I want the email to be formatted.
I mean look like a web page.
A few formatting is working like font, bold, 
but rest like div background color, fieldset etc are not.
How to send them?

As we get the promotional mails in our inbox

Comment: Show us the code what have you done?

Comment: I have a email header in which i have put in some random data. I tried <div style="background-color:pink;"> these sort. but didnt show up. table is visible but not background colors .....<div style="background-color:pink;">
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Personalia:</legend>
Name: <input type="text" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" /><br />
Date of birth: <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div> I had put this , it appears as it is whithout space

Comment: Don't even think about trying to put [forms into emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316715/html-form-in-email).

Comment: Umm, ok, I will keep that in mind.but if i remove forms still its the same.

Comment: hello zade,now check my answer

Comment: I read that images's full path should be given in src, but still its not displaying in the email it just comes as the tag. i gave some src like "http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=ubuntu&sa=N&channel=fs&biw=1280&bih=687&tbm=isch&tbnid=AK3T-HOock3TsM:&imgrefurl=http://helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/image_mag.html&docid=yV1dR8DAGi1P9M&imgurl=http://helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/image_euv_press.jpg&w=700&h=750&ei=xBqhT9vGJMf4rQfImYjhCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=689&vpy=173&dur=3057&hovh=232&hovw=217&tx=103&ty=105&sig=114917475989522455858&page=1&tbnh=148&tbnw=139&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:3,s:0,i:92"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general -
Inline CSS works in most email tools (Outlook, Gmail, . . .) 
Avoid using STYLE tag.
Store IMGes on your site and use their full path.

more tips -
http://groundwire.org/labs/email-publishing/using-css-and-html-in-email-newsletters

For more tips you need to show what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Not all that is supported. To be safe, you should do everything with tables and inline styling. Here's a list of what is and is not supported in various mail clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

You could also try starting with a HTML reset template, such as: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ which will fix some issues (but of course not add functionality).

Answer (score 0):

don't use div tags use only

```
       <table><tr><td> tags
```

for example

```
     <table>
           <tr>
            <td style=" background-color:#FF00FF; ">do something </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
```

**EDIT**

```
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Your Title</title>

        </style>
        </head>

        <body>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td style="background:url(test.png); width:200px; height:200px;">do something</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: how do i specify css? just as mentioned? not in <style> tags?

Comment: <style type="text/css"></style>

Comment: ok ok.. thank you , I will just try and come back if I have any issue

Comment: Keep in mind, `<style>` is not supported in all mail clients. I still say inline styling (`<td style="color:red;">`) is your safest bet.

Comment: okay!! I will use inline rather than the external or internal