# adding form to html email newsletter

Tags: html, forms, email, field, newsletter

Is it possible to add a form to an email newsletter? I have tried to include the code but when I send the email input fields don't show up in the email client. Any help will be appreciated.

The form code I included is:

```
<form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=GenzymeRareCommunityBlog', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true" style="border:0;" target="popupwindow">
<p>Enter your email address:</p>
<p><input name="email" style="width:140px" type="text" /></p>
<p><input name="uri" type="hidden" value="GenzymeRareCommunityBlog" /><input name="loc"   type="hidden" value="en_US" /><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" /> </p></form>
<p><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/GenzymeRareCommunityBlog" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"><img alt="" src="http://www.feedburner.com/fb/images/pub/feed-icon16x16.png" style="vertical-align:middle;border:0" /></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/GenzymeRareCommunityBlog" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">Subscribe in a reader</a></p>
<p style="font-size: smaller"><em>*We will not share your email with any other parties. <a href="privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></em></p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html form in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316715/html-form-in-email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a quick search I found this:

[Html Forms in Html Emails](http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/)

Apparently it can be done but from what I read functionality varies from email client to email client, there is a chart on the linked page that shows how different clients can be expected to handle the emails.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't see this in my search. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can add a traditional form to your email.  typically, you'll see the *illusion* of a form... like an image of a radio button, that links to a page (with an argument in the url of your selected choice) which *then* has a post / submit form button.

alternatively, you can simply link to a real form (with a nice pretty call-to-action button)