# Html forms filling in an email client?

Tags: html, email, forms, http-post

To get feedback from my customers I sent them an email with an html form in it. My customers receive the html email, fill in information and hit the submit button. The problem is that I receive a lot of post on my server that contain nothing. Not even the tracking code that is prefilled. This leads me to believe that email clients do not properly post form data. Can anyone confirm this, or let me know if I am doing something wrong. I would say about 3/5 post contains no data.

```
<p>Son, please fill this feedback</p>

<form action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
    <imput type="text" name="feedback" value="type your cries here" />
    <input type="hidden" value="{random}" name="eviltrackingcode" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I receive the post using google docs form app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding form to html email newsletter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140718/adding-form-to-html-email-newsletter)

Answer (score 3):

Email clients are terrible at HTML compared to web browsers.

I recommend using a link to your form in the mail instead (the link can contain the unique identifier which the generated form will also contain in response).

**Edit:**

Depending on your audience you might want to embed the form in an IFrame (besides using a link to it). IFrames have reasonable support (but no Gmail web-client or Blackberry):
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/