# Add radio buttons to email - what are the posibilities?

Tags: html, email, html-email, newsletter

I've been asked to provide a newsletter which allows users to check between two options. As fas as I know it's not possible nor recommended to register the answers provided on mail on a database, so I'm wondering what are my options.

1. When the user submits his answer a browser window opens with the option checked so he has to resubmit the answer and that would be registered on the database.
2. Send a mail back to the sender with the option checked so he manually manage the answers.

Is there any method you recommend? Am I missing something? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: TL;DR: Don't bother. Just send them a link to the form hosted on a web page which posts to your database.  Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/115706/passing-html-email-form-data-to-the-server-ux and https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55656/quiz-in-a-html-email-alternative-for-displaying-form-elements and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316715/html-form-in-email and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140718/adding-form-to-html-email-newsletter

Comment: Thank you for the answer and links. Unfortunately the client needs the options to be displayed but I think they can be dummy images linking to the real form. Thank you again :)

Comment: Adding it as an image will work. You can have them link to the question and populate when page loads. We call that quick start in CX world

Comment: Thanks, Syfer! That seems to be the easiest way of not messing with the design :)