# Rails 3.2 `link_to` (in email) with `method: :put` still producing GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, http, hyperlink

In my app I have automated e-mails reminding applications to complete the next step in the interview process. The e-mail has an opt out link which, when clicked, should hit a controller action that fires a state machine event to change their state to `opted_out`. The link is not working, and from the localhost console it seems to be because the link is still producing a GET request, for which there is no route (the error is `ActionController::RoutingError (Not Found):`).

Here is the console displaying the undesired GET request:

```
Started GET "/worker/application/opt_out.1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-08-29 17:08:06 +0000
Processing by LandingController#show as 
  Parameters: {"category"=>"worker/application", "location"=>"opt_out"}
```

Here is the link:

```
link_to 'stop getting these reminders', opt_out_worker_application_url(@worker), method: :put, style: 'background-color: #fff; color: #56A0D3; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-decoration: none'
```

Here are all the routes for the `worker` namespace:

```
# routes.rb

  namespace :worker do
    resource :application, only: [:create, :new, :show] do
      member do 
        put 'opt_out' => 'application#opt_out'
      end
    end
    resources :jobs do
      member do
        post 'compete' => 'jobs#compete'
        delete 'compete' => 'jobs#withdraw'
      end
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
      resources :timesheets, only: [:create, :new, :show]
    end
    resources :banks, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
    scope 'money' do
      root to: 'money#index', as: 'money'
      post 'withdraw' => 'money#withdraw', as: 'money_withdraw'
    end
    get 'profile' => 'profiles#show'
    root to: 'jobs#index'
  end
```

Here is the controller action:

```
# applications_controller.rb

      def opt_out
        @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
        if @worker.interview_requested? or @worker.onboarding_requested?
          if @worker.fire_state_event(:opt_out)
            AdminsMailer.sweeper_opted_out(@worker.id)
            redirect_to root_url, notice: "You have successfully opted out of the application process. We're sorry to see you go, and hope you'll consider returning in the future!"
          else
            redirect_to root_url, alert: "There was a problem. Please contact Support if you need further assistance."
          end
        else
          redirect_to root_url, alert: "There was a problem. Please contact Support if you need further assistance."
        end
      end
```

Here is `rake routes`:

```
opt_out_worker_application PUT    /worker/application/opt_out(.:format)           worker/application#opt_out
                worker_application POST   /worker/application(.:format)                   worker/applications#create
            new_worker_application GET    /worker/application/new(.:format)               worker/applications#new
                                   GET    /worker/application(.:format)                   worker/applications#show
```

Comment: How can a `link_to` be `PUT`? `link_to` can't have fields/form so whats the point to have it as `PUT` or `POST`?

Comment: I'm not following you because you asked two questions that seem at least semi-rhetorical. Do you have any suggestions about what I should change?

Comment: Why you want link_to as PUT?

Comment: I thought I had to do that because the route was a `PUT` route. There isn't actually a view that corresponds to the controller action I'm linking to. Newbie here! So will removing that `method:` declaration help?

Comment: yep just remove it.. if you face error about routes, show me all routes related to the controller

Comment: Yeah, still not working and I think it must be a routing problem. The route I'm trying to create is `/worker/application/1/opt_out` but I'm getting `/worker/application/opt_out.1`. Will add more routes

Comment: What does your `rake routes` show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because this is a link in context of an email. It's [documented behavior](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html):

> method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an
>   HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the
>   HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation
>   in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can
>   follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete,
>   :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the
>   request will fall back to using GET. If href: '#' is used and the user
>   has JavaScript disabled clicking the link will have no effect. If you
>   are relying on the POST behavior, you should check for it in your
>   controller's action by using the request object's methods for post?,
>   delete?, patch?, or put?.

There are security reasons to disallow executable JavaScript in emails, as well as forms. Therefore, it's impossible to render a form with JS and execute a `PUT` request, so this falls back to `GET` as stated in citation above.

Comment: Thank you. I was pretty sure what I was "trying" to do was possible because I have similar links in my admin dashboard to change Worker states and they work fine. At any rate, I was afraid that this would be the case. What is the best way to handle this? Bring the person to a page with another button that does the same thing?

Comment: @sixty4bit Should be fine. I've seen this done in many places.

Answer (score 5):

The method option on `link_to` works because your app includes some javascript that intercepts clicks on the link. That javascript creates a form with the correct method (adding an input element for request methods browsers don't support) and supports that.

This won't work in an email: your site's javascript isn't present and email clients don't usually run javascript.

Including an actual form works in some cases, but very frequently doesn't (or displays scary warnings) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316715/html-form-in-email) for example.

There's not much alternative to just having a plain "get" link unfortunately (you could of course have that go to a confirmation page where you have a button/link that will fire a post request).

Comment: Thank you. How would I pass the Worker's ID from the e-mail view to the confirmation page? I could force them to login but if there's another way, I would prefer not having to do that.

Comment: You'd have to put that or some sort of opaque token that identifies the user in the link