# Link works fine in rails view, but not in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, actionmailer

I am using Rails and ActionMailer to send emails

```
= link_to "Change", update_url(
id: @model.id, value1: "data1", :value2 => "data2"), 
:action => 'update', :method => :put
```

The above link works fine when in Rails view and it goes to the right place => update, but it goes to "new" when I integrate it into mail/email.

Any tips on why please?

Comment: I happened to answer the same question a while ago: [Rails 3.2 \`link\_to\` (in email) with \`method: :put\` still producing GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573000/rails-3-2-link-to-in-email-with-method-put-still-producing-get-request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link is being created correctly, but rails unobtrusive javascript handles actually making the link do a `put` request. Since this javascript doesn't exist in the email, the link will only be able to make a `get` request.

This email link would more usually link to the `edit` action (with a `get`), not actually perform a change directly.