# Can't send an update action to my api from an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, email, routes, actionmailer

I have a rails 5 app (API mode). I'm bootstrapping a flag comment feature. I've added a flagged attribute and a disabled attribute to my comment table (because I don't want to completely destroy comments, just to hide them on the front when disabled is true).

When a comment is flagged, I send an email (through ActionMailer) to myself with the comment, some meta data about it, and a link to update the disabled attribute to true.

My problem is that when I click this link on my mail, it doesn't update the attribute.

Here is the code to make it clear:

routes.rb:

```
resources :comments, only: [:create, :update] do
   member do
     post 'flag'
   end
end
```

controllers/api/v1/comments_controller.rb:

```
def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    new_status = @comment.disabled ? false : true

    # binding.pry => I'm not even reaching that method

    if @comment.update(disabled: new_status)
       CommentDisabledMailer.send_comment_disabled_confirmation(@comment).deliver_now
       redirect_to "https://media.giphy.com/media/YfGkjrnVIk3jq/giphy.gif" # a funny gif url
    else
       render json: { errors: @comment.errors.messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
end

def flag
   @comment.update(flagged: @comment.flagged + 1)
   render json: @comment, serializer: Api::V1::CommentSerializer, status: 201, root: nil
   FlagMailer.send_flag_mail(@comment).deliver_now
end
```

views/flag_mailer/send_flag_mail.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- some meta data about my comment -->

    <h2> <%= link_to "Disabled this comment", api_v1_comment_url(@comment), method: :put, action: :update %> </h2>

  </body>
</html>
```

I receive the mail when I flag the comment through postman, the flagged attribute is updated, but when I click on "Disable this comment" on the mail, it opens a new window with a rails error: 
`No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/comments/5"`, the disabled attribute of the comment is not updated and I obviously don't receive the mail that should confirm that the comment has been disabled (cf  the `update` method in the controller).

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Your route is a POST route. Rails normally uses JS to replace `link_to(...)method: :post` with a form that is submitted on click (normal links always make GET requests), but your link is being viewed in an email, outside of your application context, so none of Rail's unobtrusive javascript magic is taking place. Check the answers to this question which explain why put/post requests will not work in an email: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573000/rails-3-2-link-to-in-email-with-method-put-still-producing-get-request

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href="<%= api_v1_comment_url(@comment) %>" data-method="put">Disabled this comment</a>
```